# How to mock a JSON file in PHPUnit / Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I have created a Service where JSON is retrieved from an external source and queried. I want to be able to test functions that use this service, independent of the service. How do I mock the JSON file in PHP Unit Tests in order to test these functions? The JSON file formatted like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Development",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Settings",
                    "channel_types": [
                        {
                            "title": "Network"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Testing",
                    "channel_types": [
                        {
                            "title": "Social"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "created_at": 1523464038,
            "updated_at": 1523464038,
            "id": "5ace37664e1d4400a04ffaf2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could save the json as a testing file, ie. storage/testing/json/test-data.json

And then retrieve it while setting up your test:

```
$path = storage_path("testing/json/test-data.json") ;

$json = file_get_contents($path);
```